# Grub rescue (ubuntu) after booting from usb / grub_disk_native_sectors not found

Tags: dual-boot, grubrescue

After starting to **boot** from a memory stick to install **Ubuntu** (even if i didn't erase the ubuntu 18 and Windows 10 from laptop), i tryed to repaire a problem when i upgrade Ubuntu from 18 version to 22, because i got an error, after i repaire, i got another error, and so on..until i fond myself into: grub rescue>black screen. S-o i' ve found thé **normal.mod** file into (hd0, msdos9) and i loaded thé normal module. But, now i have thé error:**"grub_disk_native_sectors not found"**.

Why do this happen, and how can I erase all and install Ubuntu again?

Comment: If you have MBR(msdos), is this a 10 year old or older system? Windows has required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives since Windows 8 released in 2012. What Ubuntu live installer are you now using 22.04? What is your hardware, vendor, model & video card/chip? Can you boot live installer on USB flash drive?

Comment: You mention the *year* format in relation to Ubuntu; ie. are you asking about Ubuntu Core 18, Ubuntu Core 22 etc. as they are different products and thus upgrade/install differently to the more common *year.month* products (ie. 18 & 18.04 are different Ubuntu products; the *year* being *snap* only systems that don't require user-level packages to upgrade when you *release-upgrade* unlike the *year.month* systems). Ubuntu also has 5 installers available (over varying releases) so it matters, as some do better in some circumstances than others...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)